# Closed form for $\sqrt{1+\sqrt[2!]{2^2+\sqrt[3!]{3^3+...}}}$

Tags: limits, nested-radicals

Is there a close form for the following nested radical?

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt[2!]{2^2+\sqrt[3!]{3^3+...}}}$$

It converges and
$$\quad \quad \lim_{n \to\infty}  \sqrt{1+\sqrt[2!]{2^2+\sqrt[3!]{3^3+...+\sqrt[n!]{n^n}}}}=1.8430759846682...$$

Is this number algebraic or transcendental?

Comment: If it has a closed form, then $e$ is likely involved.

Comment: I honestly doubt that a closed form will be found, but of course you never know.

Comment: Is there any context from which the above constant arises? If this is just a radical made on a spot, I see no reason for it to have a closed form.

Comment: I conjecture that almost surely 1) it does not have a closed form 2) it is trancendental 3) nobody will be able to provide an answer (proof) in one way or another to either of the two questions.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that neither [Somos' quadratic recurrence constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos'_quadratic_recurrence_constant), nor the [nested radical constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html) are **known** to possess a closed form, I find it highly doubtful that this one will fare any better... Same as to the nature of the number, given that the nature of the afore-mentioned two constants is also unknown.

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87359/limit-of-nested-radical-sqrt1-sqrt222-sqrt333 for numerical value obtained using *Mathematica*

Comment: @QuantumDot: Never mind, I forgot to extract the square root. My sequence started $\sqrt[1!]{1^1+\sqrt[2!]{2^2+\ldots}}$